# OnReceiveAsync method missing in VS 2012

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, signalr

I am trying to develop a Signalr application using VS 2012 but i am unable to get OnreceivedAsync method as Intellisense is not pulling up.I need to override these public method but somehow its not allowing me to do that.I have included Microsoft.asp.net.signalr library also.I am developing this application in a VM. What might be the cause of it?I am including a screen shot.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of SignalR 1.0.0, the `Async` suffix has been dropped from the `OnReceivedAsync` method as well as the `OnConnectedAsync`, `OnReconnectedAsync` and `OnDisconnectedAsync` methods on `PersistentConnection`.

They are now called `OnReceived`, `OnConnected`, `OnReconnected` and `OnDisconnected` respectively. Otherwise little has changed about these methods. They all have the same method signatures and are called at the same times as before.

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/PersistentConnection